# Same variable on both sides - how can I resolve this?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a regression which is supposed to capture the effect of R&&D expenditures on stock returns, given some controllers X1, X2 and volatility, i.e. my model looks like this:

$Return = \beta_0 + \beta_1*RDEXP+\beta_2*X_1 + \beta_3*X_2+\beta_4*volatility$

I want to use volatility as a measure of riskiness of the respective stock. The problem with all risk measures is that they somehow depend on the stock price or returns, i.e. I have the same variable on the RHS and LHS. In this case,

$Return = 1+ (p_1-p_0)/p_0$

and

$volatility = \sigma_r/(tradingdays)$

Comment: I wonder if this question might do better on the [quant.SE] SE site. If you think so, flag it for the moderators to migrate it.

Comment: ^ I think it's a basic linear regression question and should be answerable here provided the OP clarifies her question a bit: (a) what are $p_0$, $p_1$, (b) it is not clear you have the same variable on RHS-LHS, please explain. Further, having "the same variable on LHS and RHS" is usually just a model badly written, for example:
$y = ax + b +0.5y$, really is just $0.5y = ax+b$. If you have non-linear dependencies, then it becomes a non-linear regression... but that's probably not what you have although I can't be sure.

Comment: p0 and p1 are the stock prices at time 0 and 1 and $\sigma_r$ is the standard deviation of the daily logarithmic returns of a stock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a model for volatility that depends on past returns and not on the return at the current time (the variable which you are trying to predict). In that case you don't have the problem. 
If that is not the case, please explain your  expression for volatility.

Comment: yes thats true! Isnt that some kind of problem with lagged variables (is that the right word for it?)

Comment: Yes. So you don't have the same variable on LHS and RHS.

Comment: Thank you for your clarificatiion Aniruddha! Very much appreciated! (If I have a past observation of the LHS on the RHS, as in my case, are there better models than a normal regression (using fixed- or random effects models) to measure the impact? I have no idea about ARMA models, but don' they deal with this kind of relationship?)

Comment: @Ann-Katrin Sorry, I'm not sure about ARMA models. You may want to try posting this as another question.